# Error in installing R script packages in CMD

Tags: r, cmd

There are packages like "rio" and "xlsx" which I need to use. But I want to run Script in CMD, not in R Studio. While installing those packages in CMD using `install.packages("rio")`  I get the error >

> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL
>   'https://cran.r-projec t.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file
>   'C:/Users/1339882/Documents/R/R-3.5.1 /doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'

And the installation don't proceed even after CRAN mirror selection.

Comment: You can specify the CRAN mirror to use in the `repos` option of `install.packages`. Does this help?

Comment: It didn't help, I've tried C:\>Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin>RScript.exe  -e "install.packages('igraph', repos='https://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/')"

Comment: For me this works: `Rscript -e "install.packages('rio', repo='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"`

Comment: Please post the error message you get when specifying the CRAN mirror.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent it worked for me, I went long way.